# Tensorflow. js training data in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a student and new to the concept of Artificial intelligence  using Tensorflow library.I have the below code and I need an interpretation for the part that has === "setosa" ? 1 : 0,

```
  //tensor of output for training data
  const outputData = tf.tensor2d(
  iris.map((item) => [
  item.species === "setosa" ? 1 : 0,
  item.species === "virginica" ? 1 : 0,
  item.species === "versicolor" ? 1 : 0,
  ])
);
```

What does this ? 1 : 0 mean here.

Comment: It means: if item.species is the same as "setosa" then it is 1 else it is 0. The outcome (1 or 0) will be then placed in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `? :` operator is called a **Conditional (ternary) operator**

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator
> that takes three operands: a condition followed by a question mark
> (?), then an expression to execute if the condition is truthy followed
> by a colon (:), and finally the expression to execute if the condition
> is falsy. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if
> statement.

See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

In your case either 1 or 0 will be the outcome.

Imagine it being like the `if` - `else` functionality. If the statement before the question mark `?` is not `false` or `undefined` the resulting value is 1 if not it's 0.